# When Clicking Hamburger icon navigation drawer not showing up

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to implement a navigation drawer in my about us page, but the problem is it doesn't show up when pressing the hamburger Menu button at the top left corner of the screen. I'm setting the about us content using the About Us library using Java that I got from github. I tried asking the problem from ChatGPT and it said that there was a problem in line 61 "navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);". I don't understand the error. I'm so lost in the problem. Could some help me out on this.
I'm providing the screenshot of my aboutus.xml, java file and log cat file and also a screenshot of the emulator.

aboutUs.java

```
package com.example.mathprojectraoli;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

import mehdi.sakout.aboutpage.AboutPage;


public class aboutUs extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_us);

        ActionBar actionBar;
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

        View aboutPage = new AboutPage(this)
                .isRTL(false)
                .setDescription(
                        "This app is intended to be a supplement for the teaching " +
                        "and learning of Math 174 Discrete Math for Computer " +
                        "Science at the University of South Carolina Aiken. " +
                        "It started with an assignment of CSCI 340 Mobile Application " +
                        "Development at the University of South Carolina Aiken " +
                        "and evolved into the current form."
                )
                .addGroup("CONNECT WITH US!")
                .addEmail("RaoL@usca.edu")
                .create();

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        setContentView(aboutPage);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.home:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                break;
            case R.id.Share:
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                myIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String body = "Your body here";
                String sub = "Your Subject";
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, sub);
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share Using"));
                break;
            case R.id.AboutUs:
                Intent aboutUs = new Intent(this, aboutUs.class);
                startActivity(aboutUs);
                break;
            case R.id.Contacts:
                Intent contactUs = new Intent(this, contacts.class);
                startActivity(contactUs);
                break;
        }
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item){
        if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_about_us.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".aboutUs"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/menu_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_main_menu"
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Logcat Error

```
2024-01-23 11:00:20.753 8827-8917/com.example.mathprojectraoli E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(335)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
2024-01-23 11:00:21.597 8827-8917/com.example.mathprojectraoli E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(335)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
2024-01-23 11:00:28.590 8827-8827/com.example.mathprojectraoli E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mathprojectraoli, PID: 8827
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mathprojectraoli/com.example.mathprojectraoli.aboutUs}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.mathprojectraoli.aboutUs.onCreate(aboutUs.java:61)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
2024-01-23 11:04:16.040 9183-9226/com.example.mathprojectraoli E/cr_VariationsUtils: Failed reading seed file "/data/user/0/com.example.mathprojectraoli/app_webview/variations_seed": /data/user/0/com.example.mathprojectraoli/app_webview/variations_seed (No such file or directory)
2024-01-23 11:04:16.738 9183-9271/com.example.mathprojectraoli E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(335)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
2024-01-23 11:04:18.168 9183-9271/com.example.mathprojectraoli E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(335)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_SUCCESS
```